# implement MSSQL function inside a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a query that eventually call the function [dbo].[HexToDec] in the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO #KeyValuePairs (SourceRowId, [Key], [Value])
SELECT 
    sv1.SourceRowId,
    sv1.Item AS [Key],
    [dbo].[HexToDec](sv2.Item) AS [Value]
FROM 
    SplitValues sv1
JOIN 
    SplitValues sv2 ON sv1.SourceRowId = sv2.SourceRowId AND sv1.RowNum = sv2.RowNum - 1
WHERE 
    sv1.RowNum % 2 = 1
```

how can implement the function inside query instead the row '[dbo].HexToDec AS [Value]'
so i don't have to call the function?

here is the function:

```
USE [Northwind]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[HexToDec]    Script Date: 23/03/2024 15:22:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[HexToDec] (@hexString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NUMERIC(38, 0)  -- Changed return type to NUMERIC with precision 38
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT, @len INT
    DECLARE @decValue NUMERIC(38, 0), @digit CHAR(1), @currentValue NUMERIC(38, 0)
    SET @decValue = 0
    SET @i = 1
    SET @len = LEN(@hexString)

WHILE (@i <= @len)
    BEGIN
        SET @digit = SUBSTRING(@hexString, @len - @i + 1, 1)
        SET @currentValue = 
            CASE 
                WHEN @digit BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN CAST(@digit AS NUMERIC(38, 0))
                WHEN @digit BETWEEN 'A' AND 'F' THEN CAST(ASCII(@digit) - 55 AS NUMERIC(38, 0))
                WHEN @digit BETWEEN 'a' AND 'f' THEN CAST(ASCII(@digit) - 87 AS NUMERIC(38, 0))
                ELSE 0
            END
        
        -- Manually compute the power of 16 since POWER function can overflow with big numbers
        IF @i > 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @j INT = 1
            WHILE @j < @i
            BEGIN
                SET @currentValue = @currentValue * 16
                SET @j = @j + 1
            END
        END
        
        SET @decValue = @decValue + @currentValue
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN @decValue
END
```

Comment: why, do you want that any way, the function is fast and would make the query unnecessary complex

Comment: i know but i have my reason

Comment: can you please provide data and table structure, so far as it is needed

Comment: How large can these numbers be? How many digits?

Answer (score 1):

I'd first of all simplify the function to get rid of the looping.

The longest hex string that you can represent without overflowing `numeric(38,0)` is `4B3B4CA85A86C47A098A223FFFFFFFFF`.

The below version divides this string up into 3 segments and returns the same results for the test values here https://dbfiddle.uk/fc0kYNOT

```
CREATE   FUNCTION [dbo].[HexToDec2] (@hexString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NUMERIC(38, 0)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @decValue NUMERIC(38, 0);

SELECT @decValue = 
       p1 * 79228162514264337593543950336 /*pow(16,24)*/ +
       p2 * 281474976710656 /*pow(16,12)*/ +
       p3 
FROM (VALUES (@hexString)) V1(hexString)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',36) + V1.hexString,36)))V2(paddedHexString)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 1,12),1))),
                    CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 13,12),1))),
                    CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 25,12),1))))
                    )V3(p1, p2, p3)


RETURN @decValue
END
```

This logic is much easier to inline in your query

```
SELECT 
    sv1.SourceRowId,
    sv1.Item AS [Key],
    p1 * 79228162514264337593543950336 + p2 * 281474976710656 + p3  AS [Value]
FROM 
    SplitValues sv1
JOIN 
    SplitValues sv2 ON sv1.SourceRowId = sv2.SourceRowId AND sv1.RowNum = sv2.RowNum - 1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',36) + sv2.Item,36)))V2(paddedHexString)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 1,12),1))),
                    CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 13,12),1))),
                    CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8),'0x0000'+ SUBSTRING(paddedHexString, 25,12),1))))
                    )V3(p1, p2, p3)
WHERE 
    sv1.RowNum % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data i assume that sv2.item is a decimal with a 0x i front

The rest can be done with convert.

```
INSERT INTO #KeyValuePairs (SourceRowId, [Key], [Value])
SELECT 
    sv1.SourceRowId,
    sv1.Item AS [Key],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,0),CONVERT (binary(1),sv2.Item,1)) AS [Value]
FROM 
    SplitValues sv1
JOIN 
    SplitValues sv2 ON sv1.SourceRowId = sv2.SourceRowId AND sv1.RowNum = sv2.RowNum - 1
WHERE 
    sv1.RowNum % 2 = 1
```

Comment: the function i want to implement done more then that

Comment: still provide data, so that i can compare